# Incorrect Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having some trouble understanding how `@Razor` works in a view. The code below is my view where a user can create a new post (I'm creating a forum)

What I want to do is remove the `<Fieldset>`
My problem is that I can't change the code I've marked.

```
@model Forum3.Models.Posts

<h2>CreatePost</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
//--- CAN'T EDITED ----
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post</legend>
        @*SET TopicID*@
        @{
Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TopicId);
@Html.Hidden("TopicId",ViewData["currentTopicId"]);
           }
//----END----

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If I remove the `<Fieldset`> and `<Legend`> I get this error on my `HiddenFor` code:
`Parser Error Message: Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.`

If I then remove the `@{...}` to look like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TopicId);
@Html.Hidden("TopicId",ViewData["currentTopicId"]);
```

I'll get an error when I click `Create` because the TopicId is not being set to my `currentTopicId` (This also happens if I leave the `<fieldset>` in)

I have no idea what going on here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having any errors with that once you remove the surrounding block and use the `@` on both fields. However, one thing you do have that's probably messing up your post - you have both a `Hidden` and a `HiddenFor` for the same property. So if you look at the rendered markup, you'll see it there twice, so it gets posted twice (I'm not sure which one it assigns to the posted model).

The `HiddenFor` is all you need - just make sure your model contains the `TopicId` value, and you don't need it in `ViewData` at all, so you can get rid of that second one.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! I didn't quite get how I could get the model to contain the `TopicId` so I just kept the ViewData.